# How to implement admin product form's "Categories" field in category form?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

in magento 2.1 there is user friendly box generated for "Categories" field. [image]

I am trying to apply this box for custom field in category form, but without success so far.

I tried to create similar, like in https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.0-rc3/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Categories.php, but without success. It makes it harder, that form implementation is different between product and category.

XML file for category form https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.0-rc3/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

XML file for product form https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.0-rc3/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

Someone knows, how to achieve this ?

Comment: Please Follow the link : [click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199440/magento-2-custom-module-grid-form-need-smart-tags/199446#199446)

Answer (score 0):

I have the beginning of the anwser. When you create your form, you have to set up a new field type like this:

```
   $fieldset->addType(
    'categories',
    '\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Category'
   );
```

Then you can use it :

```
        $fieldset->addField(
        'categories_id',
        'categories',
        [
            'name' => 'categories_id',
            'label' => __('Categories'),
            'title' => __('Categories')

        ]
    );
```

And then you will have your categories field! But last issue the rendering is broken because Magento use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Categories to enhance it. I don't know how to use this modifier to apply it on the custom categories field.