# magento 2 custom module grid form need smart tags

Tags: magento2, adminform, category-tree

I need to add admin grid form list out all category like this
[image]

Any one guide me

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your .xml file

```
<field name="parent">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Parent Category</item>
            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.parent</item>
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
            </item>
        </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Comment: In my module i not use ui-component,  i am using blocks